# Custom ListView adapter, strange ImageView behavior

Tags: android, caching, android-listview, adapter

I have a custom `ListView` `Adapter`, with which I'm creating rows for a list. My problem is though, that it doesn't seem to be distinguishing the `ImageView`s, from each other. It seems to be randomly picking `ImageViews` to chuck into place as I scroll up and down. The text information (omitted from this snippet) does not break. It works as one would expect.

Here is the relevant method of my `Adapter`:

```
  public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
  {
    View v = convertView;

    if( v == null )
    {
      LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      v = vi.inflate( R.layout.generic_row, null );
    }

    // find the image
    ImageView favImage = (ImageView)v.findViewById( R.id.toggle_favorite );

   // when clicked...
   favImage.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick( View v )
     {
       // make the gray star a yellow one
       int newImage = R.drawable.ic_star_yellow_embossed;
       ((ImageView)v).setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), newImage));
     }

   });

  return v;
  }
```

Comment: @Waqas: Ignore that, that was me copy, pasting, and stripping stuff out in my class. It is named correctly in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That behavior appears because the `ListView` recycles the row views as you scroll the list up and down, and because of this you get rows that were acted on by the user(the image was changed) in position were the image should be unmodified. To avoid this you'll have to somehow hold the status of the `ImageView` for every row in the list and use this status to set up the correct image in the `getView()` method. Because you didn't say how exactly did you implement your adapter I will show you a simple example.

First of all you should store your the statuses of the `ImageView`. I used an `ArrayList<Boolean>` as a member of the custom adapter, if the position(corresponding to the row's position in the list) in this list is `false` then the image is the default one, otherwise if it is `true` then the user clicked it and we should put the new image:

```
private ArrayList<Boolean> imageStatus = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
```

In your custom adapter constructor initialize this list. For example if you put in your adapter a list of something then you should make your `imageStatus` as big as that list and filled with `false`(the default/start status):

```
//... initialize the imageStatus, objects is the list on which your adapter is based
for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
    imageStatus.add(false);
}
```

Then in your `getView()` method:

```
View v = convertView;

            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.adapters_adapter_with_images, null);
            }

            // find the image
            ImageView favImage = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.toggle_favorite);
            // Set the image bitmap. If the imageStatus flag for this position is TRUE then we
            // show the new image because it was previously clicked by the user
            if (imageStatus.get(position)) {
                int newImage = R.drawable.ic_star_yellow_embossed;
                favImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        getContext().getResources(), newImage));
            } else {
                // If the imageStatus is FALSE then we explicitly set the image
                // back to the default because we could be dealing with a
                // recycled ImageView that has the new image set(there is no need to set a default drawable in the xml layout)                                       
                int newImage = R.drawable.basket_empty; //the default image
                favImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        getContext().getResources(), newImage));
            }
            // when clicked... we get the real position of the row and set to TRUE
            // that position in the imageStatus flags list. We also call notifyDataSetChanged
            //on the adapter object to let it know that something has changed and to update!
            favImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Integer realPosition = (Integer) v.getTag(); //get the position from the view's tag
                    imageStatus.set(realPosition, true); //this position has been clicked be the user
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify the adapter
                }

            });
            // set the position to the favImage as a tag, we later retrieve it
            // in the onClick method
            favImage.setTag(new Integer(position));
            return v;

        }
```

This should work well if you don't plan to dynamically modify the list(remove/add rows), otherwise you'll have to take care of also modifying that list of `imageStatus` to reflect the changes. You didn't say what was your row data, another approach(and the right one if you plan to do something if the user clicks that image(besides changing it)) is to incorporate the status of the image in the row's data model. Regarding this here are some tutorials:

[Android ListView Advanced Interactive](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive/) 
or [Commonsware-Android Excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) (Interactive rows)

Answer (score 2):

you need to define the default image right after finding its reference:

```
// find the image
ImageView favImage = (ImageView)v.findViewById( R.id.toggle_favorite );
//setting to default
favImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_image);
// when clicked...
favImage.setOnClickListener....
```

you need to do this because once the image is changed, and you scroll the ListView , it reappears because ListView recycles the item views. So you need to define it in **getView** to use a default image when the list is scrolled

Comment: I don't understand. I'm trying to do this when the image is clicked. I am already setting its default image in the .xml file.

Comment: setting it in xml is once, which is achieved in `if( v == null )`, but afterwards when ListView recycles the views, it doesn't read from xml, it simply recycles the views and in that case your ImageView contains the old image defined when clicked. Simply set the default image in code too and i'm sure it will work