# how to pass imageview into listview an android

Tags: android-layout

```
please see the below code 
      //here i call the gallery view
        Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
            g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, json));

        //image adapter class
      public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Bitmap bmp;
          private ImageView[] mImages;
          String[] itemimage;

       public ImageAdapter(Context context, JSONArray imageArrayJson) {
        this.mImages = new ImageView[imageArrayJson.length()];
        String qrimage;
         try
       {
        private Image View[] mImages; 
       for (int i = 0; i < imageArrayJson.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject image = imageArrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
        qrimage = image.getString("itemimage");


        byte[] qrimageBytes = Base64.decode(qrimage.getBytes());

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimageBytes,
                                            0,
                                            qrimageBytes.length);
        mImages[i] = new ImageView(context);

        mImages[i].setImageBitmap(bmp);  

       my xml view
       <Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/gallery"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
```

i can view the images through url using json i can get in gallery layout . i want get the same data into listview.please help me

I am getting all the json data using url to the android i pass the image adapter class  here here gallery view can appears using gallery .. i want vew the images instead of gallery to listveiw

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an own adapter.
And you have to supply an own layout for the listview items

Maybe this discussion give an impression

[Custom ListView adapter, strange ImageView behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754057/android-listview-adapter-strange-imageview-behavior)

Or this tutorial

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: i can display all images in gallery view i want view all images in list view

Comment: please see the above code how can i pass the list view please help me

Comment: I don't think your code above will work. Maybe you check to link with the tutorial